# Login failed after cloning live wordpress site to local wampserver

Tags: authentication, localhost, clone

This is what I did:

1. Copy all files in public_html to C:\wamp\www\mylocalsite.com
2. Export my database and rename all http://mylivesite.com to http://localhost/mylocalsite.com of exported .sql file using
   notepad++
3. Change database name, database username and database password in wp-config.php to my new database name, username and password that I
   created in my local phpmyadmin

All done with no error. When I try to login using mylivesite.com login data, but it failed with no error notification.

My question is there any easy solution for me so then I can login to my localsite admin dashboard successfully?

Comment: I did try: reset password in database with MD5 dropdown option, but login still failed

Answer (score 0):

> Export my database and rename all http://mylivesite.com to http://localhost/mylocalsite.com of exported .sql file using notepad++

This is corrupting your database because several content is serialised and must be unserialized first before doing changes there.

Use a plugin like "WP migrate db" to search and replace the strings.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?type=term&q=migrate+db

If its ok to have you staging and testing site on the same server where the live site is located than you could also give WP Staging a try:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-staging/